# How do you send validation errors to a blade view using the Validator facade? Error: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

How do I use `validateWithBag90` in Laravel 9? I tried a lot of combinations and I'm getting a bit frustrated.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'old' => 'required',
    'new' => 'required|string|confirmed',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', $validator);
}
```

I'm getting this error.

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Manually Creating Validators](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators)

> After determining whether the request validation failed, you may use
> the `withErrors` method to flash the error messages to the session. When
> using this method, the `$errors` variable will automatically be shared
> with your views after redirection, allowing you to easily display them
> back to the user. The `withErrors` method accepts a validator, a
> `MessageBag`, or a PHP `array`.

Instead of:

```php
// ...
->with('error', $validator); ❌
// ...
```

Use this:

```php
// ...
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()
                        ->back()
                        ->withErrors($validator) ✅
                        ->withInput();
        }
// ...
```

#### Addendum

[Displaying The Validation Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

> An `$errors` variable is shared with all of your application's views
> by the `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware,
> which is provided by the `web` middleware group. When this middleware is
> applied an `$errors` variable will always be available in your views,
> allowing you to conveniently assume the `$errors` variable is always
> defined and can be safely used. The `$errors` variable will be an
> instance of `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag`.

```php
<!-- /resources/views/post/create.blade.php -->
 
<h1>Create Post</h1>
 
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
 
<!-- Create Post Form -->
```

Comment: and how to show error in blade?

Comment: @OmarMalas Please, check my **Addendum** section in the edited answer.